# Where can I find map data for Northern Territory State, Australia?

Tags: data, australia

Could you please say where I can find the layers for Australia?

I need just Northern Territory State

I need basic layers like buildings, roads and others in shape format apart from the cloudmade.

Answer (score 3):

You can download it in shapefile format from the [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/australia-oceania/) but I don't know about the quality and quantity of data regarding Australia.

It seems you can specifically find Northern Territory boundaries [here](http://data.gov.au/dataset/northern-territory-electoral-boundaries-current/). You then run an intersection to get data on desired area with that [wonderful tool named QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/). Here is a [video tuorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tmk16FloieQ) regarding intersection.

Comment: Yes, but i need just a peace of Australia, not full data

Comment: please, see my edit on main reply